# Should properties of constants be capitalized?

Tags: javascript, typescript, conventions

I know that it is conventional to capitalize constant values in programming, but would you do the same for their keys? I am trying to make a string based enum in javascript:

```
const SEASONS = {
  spring: 'spring',
  summer: 'summer',
  fall: 'fall',
  winter: 'winter'
}

// or

const SEASONS = {
  SPRING: 'spring',
  SUMMER: 'summer',
  FALL: 'fall',
  WINTER: 'winter'
}
```

Is it conventional to capitalize the keys, if they are also constant? So that you access their values by `SEASONS.SPRING` instead of `SEASONS.spring`?

Comment: It's a usual convention that constants are uppercase but it boils down to the agreed upon convention with the development team.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#basic_const_usage), Constants can be declared with uppercase or lowercase, but a common convention is to use all-uppercase letters.

There is no specific rule that the declaration **SHOULD** be in uppercase.

Uppercase indicates that the variable is a constant and they are immutable.

But the properties inside a constant are mutable and hence they **CAN** be declared as lowercase.

```
const SEASONS = {
  spring: 'spring',
  summer: 'summer',
  fall: 'fall',
  winter: 'winter'
}
```

`SEASONS` are immutable but `SEASONS.spring` is mutable, hence that **CAN** be considered as lowercase.

And again, there is no predefined rule for this. Its upto you, but you should follow the same pattern throughout the application.

Comment: But what if you use `Object.freeze()` when defining the object? Then the properties are immutable.